# Is it possible to delete "classic" ssl certificates from a target-https-proxy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-proxy

I recently updated a target-https-proxy to use a certificate map:

```
$ gcloud compute target-https-proxies list
NAME                             SSL_CERTIFICATES                             URL_MAP           CERTIFICATE_MAP
lb-global-legacy-target-proxy-2  cert-lb-global-legacy2,cert-lb-globalegacy3  lb-global-legacy  cert-map-1
```

My question is: How can I delete `cert-lb-global-legacy2` and `cert-lb-globalegacy3` since they are no longer needed due to `cert-map-1`?

Is this impossible?

The only workaround seems to be to:

1. Create a new target-https-proxy that omits the ssl_certificates during creation
2. Create a new forwarding rule with a new IP address that uses the new target-https-proxy (because it seems like forwarding rules are also immutable; can't use existing ip address because it is currently in use by a different forwarding rule)
3. Go into DNS and repoint every subdomain to the new IP address

This seems ridiculous for what should be a simple task (remove "classic" SSL certs from a target proxy that no longer needs them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `update` command with `--clear-ssl-certificates` flag.

Example:

```
 gcloud compute target-https-proxies update PROXY_NAME --global --clear-ssl-certificates
```

That will delete classic certs, but keep certificate maps.

Docs link:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/target-https-proxies/update#--clear-ssl-certificates

Comment: This is great answer. Take note that this was only added to gcloud in 2023 so make sure you update it. You can than delete the cert with

`gcloud compute ssl-certificates delete cert-name --global`

Answer (score 1):

Since you've updated the target https-proxy, you can [delete](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs#delete-ssl-cert-resource) the SSL certificate by running the command

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates delete CERTIFICATE_NAME \
    --global
```

---

A temporary workaround will be:

1. Open Cloud Shell and run the below command :

```
gcloud compute target-https-proxies export (Load_Balancer_Name) > /tmp/proxy
```

2. Edit /tmp/proxy file manually, Run the command :

```
- cat /tmp/proxy
```

3. Remove the below lines from the file :

```
sslCertificates:
           https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/...
```

4. After removing the lines, save the file by using `‘CTRL + O’` and exit from the file `‘CTRL+X’` .
5. Then import the file with certificates removed.

```
gcloud compute target-https-proxies import (Load_Balancer_Name) --source=/tmp/proxy
```

6. And then you should be able to delete the certificate.

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates delete <certificate name>
```

Comment: Hmm, I had tried that, but I get `- The ssl_certificate resource 'projects/production/global/sslCertificates/cert-lb-global-legacy2' is already being used by 'projects/production/global/targetHttpsProxies/lb-global-legacy-target-proxy-2'`

Comment: Hello, I added another workaround that you may try

Comment: @Gillespie I have the same issue. Were you able to resolve it with this workaround?

Comment: Sorry, ran out of time to try it. I just decided to move on without deleting the old certs.